# What exactly is the data returned when reading a .wav file?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav

When reading a audio file using something such as

```
rate, wavData = scipy.io.wavfile.read('test.wav')
```

what exactly does the data inside of `wavData` represent?

Comment: wavData is an array of points on the audio curve as it wobbles up and down ... typically integers often 16 bits so a single point is stored in two consecutive bytes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wavData is an array of numbers each representing a single sample of the audio signal. The samples are snapshots of the audio amplitude spaced evenly in time. So if your rate is returned as 48000 then the first 48000 elements of wavData would be 1 second worth of the audio signal.  For more information read about PCM on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation.

Comment: And what if the recording is stereo?

Comment: If the recording is stereo, `wavData` has shape (n, 2).  The two columns are the left and right channels.

Comment: is there any information lost during the reading process? because we could also read it into binaries using open function